# systemd requires="some non-systemd process"?

Tags: debian, systemd

I have not found a way for systemd to recognize that some required non-systemd process is required to be running before I start mine. In Upstart I could do, for example,

```
if pgrep -f bin/postgres
```

The closest I've found is "path based activation", which would let me look for a lock file, but this is clunky and not guaranteed since sometimes lock files get orphaned.

I do not want to rewrite all the processes that are not using systemd so that they now do use it - I just want to start one particular process that way.

Is there no such option, or have I just not found it?

Comment: Read the manual, you can learn to write a service file. There's no such concept called non-systemd process

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 Obviously I will be writing a service file *for my own application*. I have spent many hours and looked at literally dozens of web pages that discuss how to use systemd. Not one of them has given me any clues on how to reference a process which is not under the direct and initial control of systemd. It sounds like you are telling me that all processes MUST and DO use systemd. I explained that I want to make minimal changes to the system, and asked *if this was possible*. If the answer is "No it is no possible", please say so if you know. Otherwise, clues beyond "RTFM" are appreciated.

Comment: Systemd manage SERVICES not PROCESSES. "a process under the direct and initial control of systemd" "a process use systemd" Don't say none phrases you can't give exact definition. If you want to test if some program is running and decide whether to start your app, try pgrep in ExecStarPre option. Or ConditionXXX option, or make a script warper and do your own check-then-start logic.

Comment: From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.service.5.html  : "A unit configuration file whose name ends in .service encodes information about a *process* controlled and supervised by systemd." Clearly, some processes are controlled by systemd, but some may not be. Systemd manages services, and many services manage processes. Thank you for pointing out ExecStartPre, and of course I can write scripts to do whatever systemd does not, but that *does not answer my question* about what systemd *does* or *does not* do itself.

Comment: Systemd provides so much functionality that you can easily make almost any program started as a service. Including your script. You write services for existing programs so they can be started as systemd services. Systemd cares about the state of a service, not a process, nor what code it's currently executing.

Comment: Notice the word "process". There's huge difference between process running a program and a particular process, a process is no longer a process running a particular program once it exec another program, but still THE process(the same `struct task`) whatever code it's excuting. You're requiring the former, not latter.

Comment: Service is completely userspace concept. It's a `. service` unit with some overrides config (e.g. `xx.service.d`). Systemd manage them and assign states like enabled/disabled/masked, running/fail/exited for them. Service themselves define actions like ExecStart ExecStop so systemd know what to do when user want to start/stop an service. Basically systemd do this by creating cgroups and processes  in them to run predefined actions(I mean, almost every piece of code needs to be run within some process, systemd HAVE TO create processes to run the actions, right).

Comment: Although sometimes systemd DO send SIGKILL to processes in cgroups when an illy-written service can't correctly stop, but it doesn't have too much choices, the user WANT THE SERVICE TO DIE(you wouldn't want to see a cgroup with some processes in it still existing after you request the service to stop, right?)

Comment: Said another way, you want your systemd service to *check for* another process to be running (and fail if it's not); *or* to start the other process if it's not already running, before then starting your processes?

Comment: @JeffSchaller In the interest of not ruffling any more feathers let's call it a program or application rather than a process, which is probably more accurate/correct/truthful in any case. Yes, I wanted systemd to see whether an application that was not under the control of systemd was already running, and to not start my application unless the other was running. I would not expect it to start the other, since the other was by definition unknown to systemd. At this point my interest is academic (I have worked around it) but I am still curious to know how/if systemd deals with things like this.

Comment: Systemd itself can't deal with such things in general, it's not `pgrep`. Although it DO detect something(like file existence) if service using ConditionXXX option. Again, The idea of systemd is manage services, not programs or processes, of course a program can run without being a systemd service, but systemd wouldn't notice or care about that. That's why it provides ExecStartPre option, which allows you to do preparation using ANY logic you like before your service actually start.

Answer (score 1):

The best option I can think of is the one that [炸鱼薯条德里克](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/301641/%e7%82%b8%e9%b1%bc%e8%96%af%e6%9d%a1%e5%be%b7%e9%87%8c%e5%85%8b) mentioned in a comment: [`ExecStartPre`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

```
# ...
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/pgrep -f bin/postgres
# ...
```

This honors the instruction that:

> ExecStartPre= may not be used to start long-running processes

... because `pgrep` exits when it's done. It also achieves the desired functionality by allowing the service to start if the listed process exists and prevents the start of the service when the listed process does not exist.

If you attempt to start the service manually when the requisite process does not exist, you get:

> Job for demo.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status demo.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.