# How to run a daemon only when a specific application is running?

Tags: systemd, daemon

I have a user-space daemon, call it `maxwell`, that executes various actions based on D-bus signals from another application, call it `room`. I would like to run `maxwell` as soon as the user starts `room`, and stop it when `room` exits.

I think a launcher script like this would result in the desired behaviour:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

systemctl --user start maxwell
room
systemctl --user stop maxwell
```

but is there a better / standard way to do it, e.g. via systemd itself?

*Update:* It seems like the functionality I'm looking for is similar to what `upstart` used to provide with its [dbus event](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/dbus-event.7.html). The closest thing that can be achieved with `systemd` appears to be auto-starting a service which "owns" a certain D-bus name when that name is first used, as per Stephen Kitt's answer; unfortunately, in this case it is `room` that "owns" the name.

---

*Note:* I don't think that this is the same as [systemd requires="some non-systemd process"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/525693/34530) or, at least, that the answer provided therein works in this case. As far as I understand, using `ExecStartPre` would simply mark the `maxwell` unit as *failed* if `room` wasn't already running.

Comment: yes. Please read about systemd unit files and ask more concrete questions.

Comment: @arved Could you be more explicit? I read the whole `systemd.unit` man page multiple times before asking this, and couldn't find what I was looking for. The question also seems pretty concrete to me. I could give you the names of the precise programs I'm running, but that wouldn't change anything for the problem itself. Also, I am under the impression that more general, yet _answerable in a precise manner_, questions are preferred on SE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [systemd requires="some non-systemd process"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525693/systemd-requires-some-non-systemd-process)

Comment: The title doesn't match the body. If Maxwell doesn't needs to to running when room is not, then it doesn't need to be a daemon at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

systemd supports [D-Bus activation](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/system-activation.txt), where a service is started to service a D-Bus method call. I’m not sure whether this can be transposed to user services; for system services you create a D-Bus service file:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=your.bus.name
Exec=/path/to/the/daemon
User=root
SystemdService=systemd-service-name.service
```

and a corresponding systemd service, which has to specify a matching bus name:

```
[Service]
BusName=your.bus.name
```

Specifying [`BusName`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#BusName=) in this way automatically marks the service as a D-Bus service.

It should be possible to install everything as user services (changing `User` in the D-Bus service file to match), but I haven’t tried that.

Comment: This sounds promising. I'll give it a try, thank you.

Comment: In my experiments, I could only make it work if the daemon "owns" `your.bus.name` and the application tries to connect to it: if D-Bus receives a message for the daemon and it isn't running, then D-Bus automatically starts it up before delivering the message. Is there a way to make this work if the application "owns" `your.bus.name` and the daemon simply listens in on the chatter? E.g. start the daemon the first time a well-known name is used / registered?

Comment: By the way, according to the [documentation](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-starting-services), service description files for the session bus should be placed in `dbus-1/services/` under one of the XDG data directories (e.g. `~/.local/share/`) and, unlike system bus service files, they don't require a `User` field.

Comment: Yes, D-Bus activation only really works if the service being started “owns” the activated bus.

Comment: Although it doesn't exactly solve my issue, I'm accepting this answer since it seems to be the closest result achievable through `systemd`.